# How to calculate the required torque of motor for bipedal robot

Tags: mobile-robot, motor, first-robotics, humanoid

I just create a bipedal robot in SolidWorks and after I got all components, I realise that I need select the correct motor for the robot. There will be **four motors** equipped in the robot, **two for hip and two for knee**.

I am wondering what parameters I need to know and what equations I should use to calculate the torque for the hip motor and torque for the knee motor? A photo of the design is also attached here.

[image: SolidWorks model of bipedal robot]

Comment: please do not put information into comments ... everything should be contained within the *question* ... please update your question ... then delete the comment

Comment: What are the dimensions and weight of the robot? Can you share the drive link of this robot file (Assembly file )?